# Add an existing sql to django project

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a sql file which I want to add to my django, I don't know:
where to put the file
which commands should I run for adding it

many thanks for your help.

Comment: What you mean by *adding to django*?

Comment: I mean loading the database into project's file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the database details in `settings.py`. If you have an sql file you need to load it into a database, then update `DATABASES` in settings.py

As you're using the sql file you might want to run `python manage.py inspectdb` command which will return you the model definitions for the tables present in the database.

Copy the results in `models.py` file in one of your app and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not proper by mean adding I think you may want to connect with database. If you are using **MySQL** then you need to install MySQL client [This link help you](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database#step-3-%E2%80%94-install-mysql-database-connector).